# How to transfer text,audio & image file from one peer to another using Webrtc datachannel?

Tags: javascript, networking, websocket, webrtc, p2p

I am using Chrome browser & able to pass ordinary text file from one peer to another(Browser tabs) but same logic doesnt working for audio & image file( reading & writing at other end).
Kindly help me through it using suitable example. 
I am beginner to Webrtc & datachannels.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a beginner to WebRTC, maybe the [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com) library might be something for you.
It's pretty easy to use and brings a lot of possibilities with it.
Transferring multimedia streams is supported and explained in the [docs](http://peerjs.com/docs/) as well.

The onlything really to implement is handling of multimedia streams what I can't explain to you since I'm only using Firefox.